# Moving data from one program to another program using file structures c

Tags: c, arrays, file

Program(A)-----> file.txt-----> Program(B)

^This is the format I am using, I currently don't have enough knowledge with file structures.
My text file is named `myStudents.txt`

EDIT: Program(A) writes the information properly. Program(B) needs to retrieve the information from the text file.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char studentName[50];
    int grade=0;

    printf("Which students grade would you like to retrieve?: ");
    scanf("%s",&studentName);

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = (fopen("myStudents.txt", "r"));

    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nStudent details:\n");
    fscanf(fptr,"%d %[^\n]s",grade,studentName);
    printf("Name: %s\n",studentName);
    printf("Grade: %d\n",grade);

    fclose(fptr);
return 0;
}
```

I'm very confused on how to use program A's information in program B. Apologies if this is a repeat thread, I couldn't find any information here or anywhere else to solve my issue.

*Note(A solid explanation would be very helpful along with any constructive criticism)

Cheers! Have a good day!

Comment: `scanf("%s",&studentName);` -> `scanf("%s",studentName);`

Comment: What does not work? Does program A work? If you open the text file is there the expected output? You should first determine where the problem is located.

Comment: Your program B does actually not search the file for anything, it only tries to print the first student.

Comment: @Osiris Yes, sorry I have to expected information in the file. I am unaware how to get the information back.

Comment: Removed format.

Comment: Ok, then program A is working as expected and your question reduces to searching an entry in a file, right? You should edit your question and remove program A, since it is not really relevant.

Comment: @Osiris That's correct. I just started these yesterday so apologies for lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program B does actually not search for any name, it just tries to print the first one. I won't write the complete code for you but here is a little help with what your program should do:

1. read in the file line by line. (functions `fscanf`, `fgets` or `getline` may be useful)
2. extract the name and grade out of the line. (`sscanf` and all string functions)
3. check if the name is the one you are looking for, if yes print it and stop.

This is of course only an example what the program could look like, but i suggest to start by implementing this steps.

Comment: I'm confused on how to extract the name. Do I assign the pulled name to a string then compare them that way?

Comment: I added 'I' to make grammar proper.

Comment: @Krytec Yes that would be a good way to do it. If you read the line to a string you could use `sscanf` for simple string passing to extract the name and the grade.

Comment: Thank you this seemed to have worked but I only tested the names. Thank you for the help, you made my day a hell of a lot better!

Comment: @Krytec You are welcome. If my suggestions were useful, feel free to accept it as an answer. :)